# Can't deploy Google App Engine application on local server

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to follow the instructions for running a simple new Google App Engine web application locally (without Google Web Toolkit, just the Web App) named "tunes".

I am following [these instructions](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/running_and_debugging_2_0). Step one is to make a run configuration.  I made one using all the defaults; I checked that under the *Server* tab the *"Run built-in Server"* box is checked.  However, when I Run the app, I get the Console; right below the console tab it says

```
 <terminated> tunes [Web Application] C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe (Feb 26, 2014, 5:35:44 PM)
```

then below the line is what looks like a classic Unix "Usage" error message in the console, in red type, whose first line is

```
Usage: <dev-appserver> [options] <app directory>
```

followed by a list of options, and then nothing else happens that I can see.

I tried pointing a browser at `http://localhost:8888/tunes` as suggested by the documentation, but Firefox could not find a server active at that port.

Under the Arguments tab in the Run Configuration is the following:

"-codeServerPort 9997 --port=8888 org.tunes.gaeproject.Tunes C:\Users\cdf\java\eclipse4.3.1workspace\tunes\war"

I can successfully deploy the web application to the Google App Engine site and run it there.

What do I have misconfigured?

Comment: Could you see your Arguments tab in the Run Configuration and let us know what is there. Ideally it would have the --port=8888 <war-directory-path>

Comment: Romin: I answered your question by adding the information to the original post.  I note that it is different from what you suggest in that the class "org.tunes.gaeproject.Tunes" is between the "--port=8888" and the war-directory-path, but I have no idea if that is significant.

Comment: I still don't know what the problem was, but I deleted the entire Run Configuration and regenerated it and now the server starts.

Comment: What do you notice now after deleting in the Run configuration that is working ?

Answer (score 0):

Google AppEngine application is not meant to run on local server, and neither you could create its docker image etc to deploy it anywhere you wish.

Instead I suggest you to port your application to Google Compute Engine ([GCE](https://cloud.google.com/compute/)) first within your deployment setup, which might require minor code refactorings, and [Kubernetes](http://kubernetes.io/docs/whatisk8s/) kinda auto-scaling deployment will functional equivalent to what you have now. But with approach you may port the application easily to local server setup, or a docker image to run from any virtualization environment